# Is strlen times sizeof(char) always equivalent to sizeof(literal)?

Tags: c, string, byte

Is the following always true on any implementation?

```
(strlen("some string with weird characters") + 1) * sizeof(char) 
    == sizeof("some string with weird characters");
```

I am asking if I can reliably use `(strlen(my_string) + 1) * sizeof(char)` to calculate the binary size of any string. Also, please let me know if there's a better way to do so.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is 1 _by definition_.  It is therefore bad style to multiply or divide anything by `sizeof(char)`.

Comment: @zwol: Except when you want to magically get a `size_t` type without a header to `typedef` it. ;-)

Comment: @R.. Hmm, yeah, I suppose that could be useful, but when can you not include `stddef.h`?

Comment: Yes, you can use `strlen()+1` to reliably calculate the size of any *string* but then you need to know that not all string literals describe a *string*.

Comment: A string is *a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character.*

Answer (score 8):

No. The only situation it differs in is embedded nulls:

```
(strlen("strlen can see this\0strlen cannot see this") + 1) * sizeof(char) 
    != sizeof("strlen can see this\0strlen cannot see this");
```

Also, `sizeof(char)` is always `1`, so there is no point in it being there.

---

Since  string literals are arrays of type `char[N]` (for some positive size `N`), the `sizeof` method is the correct way to get their size (But `/ sizeof(char)` is unnecessary, as it is `1`).

Answer (score 2):

<strike>No!</strike>

```
char str[20] = "abc";
```

has size 20 and string length 3.

---

Edit:
The two ways produce the same result (for that particular data), but two points to note:

`sizeof(char)` is always `1` by definition. Generally, it is better to use the size of the named variable, and then the code is more easily maintained. For example

```
char *ptr = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
```

is better as

```
char *ptr = malloc(100 * sizeof *ptr);
```

and then if you should change the type, you don't have to change the size.

The other point is that `sizeof` is computed by the compiler, but `strlen` is not computed until runtime (apart from compiler optimisation). But for a string literal if it's the size you want, then `sizeof` will generally be more efficient, since the string literal cannot change at run time.

Answer (score 0):

No, both

```
(strlen(myString) + 1) * sizeof(char)
```

and

```
sizeof(myString)
```

are not always guaranteed to be equal. If char array `myString` has number of elements in it, is different from array index mentioned, then `strlen(myString)` and `sizeof(myString)` would be different. For e.g In below case

```
char myString[10];
```

both `(strlen(myString) + 1) * sizeof(char)` and `sizeof(myString)` would results in same. But if its other case like

```
char myString[10] = "Hello";
```

than results would be different.

Also I would prefer this

```
(strlen(myString) + 1) * sizeof( *myString)
```

rather than

```
(strlen(myString) + 1) * sizeof(char)
```

as `sizeof( *myString)` looks generic.

**Side note**, if `myString` is of `char*` type i.e pointer type like

```
char *myString = "some string with weird characters";
```

or *used as function arguments* holding like

```
void myTestFunc(char *myString) { }
```

then `sizeof(myString)` won't work, `strlen(myString) + 1) * sizeof( *myString)` is more preferable.

Comment: Note that `char myString[10] = "Hello";` is not a string literal.  It is a `char` array that is initialized to contain the string `"Hello"`.  Those are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the equality will hold and could be simplified as `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition.

Note however that if the string literal contains embedded null bytes, `strlen()` will evaluate to less than the size of the literal minus 1.

Here is the shortest counter-example:

```
strlen("\0") + 1 != sizeof("\0")   // strlen("\0") is 0 but sizeof("\0") is 2
```